# Formatting variable with 2 outputs

Tags: powershell, variables, output, newline

Code:

```
$adgroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $tag$ | select -ExpandProperty Name | Sort | Select-String "iSite"
```

Output:

> DFSR Managed iSite Enterprise 4.4.542.2 WSA_Rad_A
>
> DFSR Managed iSite Radiology 4.4.516.27 WSA_Rad_A

Basically one command generates two items (output using `$variable | out-file C:\file.txt -Append`) and when I go to open these in excel they format as one line like this:

> DFSR Managed iSite Enterprise 4.4.542.2 WSA_Rad_A DFSR Managed iSite Radiology 4.4.516.27 WSA_Rad_A

Is there a way to break it up // add a new line after each item but still keep them both inside one variable?

Comment: How are you doing the output?

Comment: output using `$variable | out-file C:\file.txt -Append` and I would like to keep it in the same output method if possible.

Comment: It worked for me. Try using the Add-Content cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $tag$ | select -ExpandProperty Name | Sort | Select-String "iSite" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File C~\Desktop\Sites.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break up your request a bit.

First, you're using `Select -Expand`, which is going to discard all of the properties and only return the values for each object's Name.  This is a problem because when you export it as a CSV, you're not going to have a heading.  I think the lack of header is ultimately leading to the issue you're facing here.

Try this instead:

```
$adgroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $tag$ | Where Name -like "*iSite*" | 
  select Name | Export-Csv c:\pathto\YourCsv.Csv
```

Finally, I don't think Select-String is doing you any favors.  You could instead use the `-like` operator.

Comment: I'm exporting to a .txt file and adding in my own heading at the very end because I have more than just this one variable. Is there a way to keep the var with both items in it and insert a line break in between them? That is my goal.

Comment: Somehow you are introducing this problem with this other code. PowerShell natively adds line breaks which will just work. How about you share your complete code? Maybe we can find where the concatenation is coming from.